# How to Change the MenuItem Colors of Forms ViewList in iOS ViewCellRenderer?

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to Change the color of ContextAction Menus added in Xamarin.Forms Xaml file. `IsDestructive="True"` sets the menu color to Red. But i need another menu to look like Green or some other color.

Here is my Forms Xaml code..

```
<ListView x:Name="planList" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:SampleData.PLAN_DATA}" RowHeight="150" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnEditClick" Text="Edit" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/> <!-- THIS HAS TO BE GREEN COLOR -->
                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeleteClick" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <!--Non Editable State-->
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="28" IsVisible="{Binding isNotSaveState}">
                            <Frame  WidthRequest="130" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="#151617" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                <Label Text="{Binding from}" TextColor="#ff9600" FontSize="Medium" FontFamily="Helvetica"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <!--Editable State-->
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0"  IsVisible="{Binding isSaveState}">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="5">
                                <Label Text="From" TextColor="#838288"  FontSize="Medium" FontFamily="Helvetica"/>
                                <Entry Text="" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Button Text="Save" BackgroundColor="Green" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Clicked="onSaveClick" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here is my Renderer..

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyApp.Views.Cells.CustomViewCell), typeof(MyApp.iOS.Views.Cells.CustomViewCellRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Views.Cells
{

    public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

            // I have no Idea how to access the Swipe Menus from Renderer

            //cell.EditingAccessory
            //cell.EditingAccessoryView

            return cell;
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin implements the context menu by a native cell `ContextActionsCell` subclassing the `UITableViewCell`.

However, as of today **Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS** (1.4.0.6340-pre2) assembly, the `ContextActionsCell` that setups the gesture and buttons is still an `internal` class, which is not accessible or inheritable for changing anything.

---

BUT WAIT!

Still, you may use **Reflection** to change above `internal` stuff.

**Example:**

```cs
// Get UIImage with a green color fill
CGRect rect = new CGRect (0, 0, 1, 1);
CGSize size = rect.Size;
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (size);
CGContext currentContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
currentContext.SetFillColor (0, 1, 0, 1);
currentContext.FillRect (rect);
var backgroundImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
currentContext.Dispose ();

// This is the assembly full name which may vary by the Xamarin.Forms version installed.
// NullReferenceException is raised if the full name is not correct.
var t = Type.GetType("Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextActionsCell, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");

// Now change the static field value!
var field = t.GetField ("destructiveBackground", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
field.SetValue (null, backgroundImage);
```

*Note 1: This will change the destructive background colors of **all** context menu.*

*Note 2: If you also want to change the normal color, the field name is `normalBackground`.*

*Note 3: Xamarin may make these classes `internal` with a purpose that the API and behaviours may change in the future. Above example may break in coming releases.*

Comment: Thanks @Alex Lau that worked great.. I understand that this internal stuff may change in future...Is there any documents related to work with the Reflection API ? If so suggest me one..

Answer (score 3):

For  **Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193 & Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS (2.x)** version number **Version=2.0.0.0** and field names Case changed to **NormalBackground** & **DestructiveBackground**

```cs
using System;

using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(App.Renderers.CustomViewCellRenderer))]
namespace App.Renderers
{    
    public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

            try
            {
                // This is the assembly full name which may vary by the Xamarin.Forms version installed.
                // NullReferenceException is raised if the full name is not correct.
                var globalContextViewCell = Type.GetType("Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextActionsCell, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");

                // Now change the static field value! "NormalBackground" OR "DestructiveBackground"
                if(globalContextViewCell != null)
                {
                    var normalButton = globalContextViewCell.GetField("NormalBackground", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

                    if (normalButton != null)
                    {
                        normalButton.SetValue(null, getImageBasedOnColor("ff9500"));
                    }      

                    var destructiveButton = globalContextViewCell.GetField("DestructiveBackground", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

                    if (destructiveButton != null)
                    {
                        destructiveButton.SetValue(null, getImageBasedOnColor("B3B3B3"));
                    }                        
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in setting background color of Menu Item : " + e.ToString());
            }

            return cell;
        }

        private UIImage getImageBasedOnColor(string colorCode)
        {
            // Get UIImage with a green color fill
            CGRect rect = new CGRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
            CGSize size = rect.Size;
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);
            CGContext currentContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            currentContext.SetFillColor(Color.FromHex(colorCode).ToCGColor());
            currentContext.FillRect(rect);
            var backgroundImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            currentContext.Dispose();

            return backgroundImage;
        }


    }


}
```