# How can i implement Listview component in a xamarin cross platform instead of context action for left and right swipe?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, menuitem

SWTableViewCell is available for Xamarin iOS platform. But i want both Android and iOS Tableview to be customised with left and right swipe action using Xamarin forms.

If i need to create a custom Renderer for both platforms how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Change the MenuItem Colors of Forms ViewList in iOS ViewCellRenderer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897905/how-to-change-the-menuitem-colors-of-forms-viewlist-in-ios-viewcellrenderer)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom cell view renderer, I did it but it has limitations, I did it using the destructive background and the normal background, I am trying to get something that works with the name or other field, what you need is the destructive background, here is what I did:
In the IOS project add a file CustomCellViewRenderer.cs with the following code:

```
public class CustomCellViewRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        try
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            CGRect rect = new CGRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
            CGSize size = rect.Size;
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);
            CGContext currentContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            currentContext.SetFillColor(Color.Green.ToCGColor());
            currentContext.FillRect(rect);
            var backgroundImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            currentContext.Dispose();
            CGContext currentNormalContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            currentNormalContext.SetFillColor(Color.FromRgb(220, 220, 0).ToCGColor());
            currentNormalContext.FillRect(rect);
            var normalBackgroundImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            currentNormalContext.Dispose();

            var t = Type.GetType("Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextActionsCell, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");

            var destructive = t.GetField("DestructiveBackground", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            var normal = t.GetField("NormalBackground", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            if (destructive != null)
                destructive.SetValue(null, backgroundImage);
            if (normal != null)
                normal.SetValue(null, normalBackgroundImage);

            return cell;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var ret = new UITableViewCell();
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

and I have the constructor in the shared project as CustomCellView.cs:

```
public class CustomCellView : ViewCell
{
    public CustomCellView()
    {

    }
}
```

and the view:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDone, Source={x:Reference Name=Steps}}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                  Text="Complete" 
                                  IsDestructive="True"
                                  x:Name="Complete" />
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnStart, Source={x:Reference Name=Steps}}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                  Text="Start" 
                                  IsDestructive="False"
                                  x:Name="Start"/>
```

I want to say I found all this code in the Xamarin forums and took a bit from several sources, it works but only allows 2 colors.

I hope this helps.